# Razor component - Load and display data asynchronously

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-component

I have a Razor component displaying a list of articles and I would like to load each article's image asynchronously after the page was rendered, so that the user would see the images poping on the page one after another.

The problem is, where and how shoud I make these calls ?

The HTML:

```
@foreach (Article article in articles)
{
   <div>
      <p>@article.name</p>
      if (article.image != null) 
      {
         <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@article.image">
      }
   </div>
}
```

The code:

```
List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    articles = LoadArticles(); //Asume this function initialises the article list
}

async Task LoadPicture(Article article)
{
    await article.LoadImage(); //This will make the server call to get the base64 of the image
}
```

I would need to call the `LoadPicture` function for each of my article in the page but I would like to make asynchronously without having to wait for all of the calls to refresh the whole page.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: I would suggest thinking in the direction of a List<yourObject> newList and loop this, when you add a counter you could refresh the page after you load 10 objects. To refresh the page you can add : StateHasChanged() ... Good luck !

Comment: Can you describe the EXACT behavior that you want?  What is happening right now that you don't want?  It seems to me that your existing code will pretty much do that: articles will be displayed, and those with !null images will display their image (i.e. as they load one by one).

Comment: As @MathiasZ suggested I will try to load 10 at a time.
I didn't want to wait for the whole article list to fetch their images before I can display the page.
As of now I have 50 articles so the pages take 2 seconds to display its content which is frustrating for the user. I woul like to display the whole page with no images a all and then load them in the background and display them when they are ready.

Comment: You could also make an `Article.razor` component. For each Article in your `List<Article>` , which is looped through, you create an instance of that `Article` Component. That component takes the `Article` object as a parameter. That component makes an api call, likely in `OnInitAsync` to fetch the base64 string for only it's Article object. Doing it this way should mean that each Article component will rerender itself once the api call is completed and it's received it's image data.

Comment: The most performant way would be to serve the images by URL, not as base64. Is that an option?  How big are they?

Comment: @HenkHolterman sadly the images need to be protected by a token , using URLs is not possible. The images are relatively small 80x80 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough example of what I described you could do in my comment and it should achieve the behaviour you originally wanted.

Doing it this way means that each `Article` component takes care of itself and when it should be rendered or updated, and each api call to fetch the image data should be independant.

-- **Article List Component**

```
@foreach(var article in Articles)
{
    <Article Model="article">
}


@code {

    List<Article> Articles {get;set;}

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return LoadArticlesAsync(); //Api call to get all articles list and which sets Articles.
    }


}
```

-- **Article.razor component**

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    <h1> @Model.Title </h1>

    @if (_imageLoaded)
    {
        <img src="@ImageBase64"/>
    }
}

@code
 {
    [Parameter]
    public Article Model {get;set;}

    private bool _imageLoaded = false;
    private string ImageBase64 {get;set;}

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ImageBase64 = await LoadArticleImage();
        _imageLoaded = true;
    }
}
```